# Buttons not working with listview

Tags: android, button, android-listview, android-fragments

I have buttons across the top of my listview. The buttons do not function until I select an item from the list. According to some other posts, I should add the following line to my XML file: android:focusable="false". However, no change occurred after adding that line.

Here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    >
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >  
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chapters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="@string/chapters" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scales"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="@string/scales" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_flat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/b_flat" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_flat"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"    
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/e_flat" /> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/concert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/concert" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bass"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/bass" />  

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/video" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/practice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_layout_height"    
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="@string/practice" />                                                      
    </LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
          android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code that I use to display the list:

```
public class ChapterListFragment extends ListFragment {
private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
private ArrayList<Chapters> mChapters;
private static final String TAG = "ChapterListFragment";

private Button mChaptersButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onCreate +++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             

    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.chapters_title);
    mChapters = ChapterList.get(getActivity()).getChapters();

    ChapterAdapter adapter = new ChapterAdapter(mChapters);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        

}
```

I updated my "onListItemClick to the following:

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     //if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onListItemClick +++");       

    // Get the chapter from the adapter
    Chapters c = ((ChapterAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    //Start ImprovisationActivity
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImprovisationActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(ChapterFragment.EXTRA_CHAPTER_ID, c.getId());
    startActivity(i);
}

private class ChapterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chapters> {

    public ChapterAdapter(ArrayList<Chapters> chapters) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, chapters);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_chapter, null);
        }
        // Configure the view for this Chapter
        Chapters c = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chapter_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(c.getChapter());

        return convertView;         
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); {
    ((ChapterAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();      
    }
}
```

}

For anyone having the same problem, I added the following code to my activity and now my buttons have focus:

```
    public class ChapterListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
private static final String TAG = "ChapterListActivity";

private Button mChaptersButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onCreate +++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_improvisation);        

    mChaptersButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chapters);      

    // Need to default the button to pressed
    mChaptersButton.setSelected(true);
    mChaptersButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mChaptersButton.isSelected()){
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ onClick for mChaptersButton +++");
                    mChaptersButton.setSelected(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chapters Button Not Selected", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chapters Button Selected", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mChaptersButton.setSelected(true);
                }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ createFragment +++");
    return new ChapterListFragment();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Button` is instantiated inside your  `onListItemClick` so they won't be `clickcable` until after you click on a list item. You can move them to the `onCreate()` but then you will need to `inflate` another `View` in there also, using `setContentView()`

Also, as stated in a comment by buptcoder, I don't see an `OnClickListener` attached to the `Button`. I still don't see it being clickable until after you move it out of the listener it is in now but an `OnClickListener` will still need to be attached to the `Button`

Comment: I had the onClickListener code, but apparently did not include it in my post. (my error) The buttons do have focus after moving them out of the onListItemClick and into my onCreate for the activity. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

These buttons won't work with anything, not just a ListView.

To get the clicks (I'm assuming that's what you want) working, have your Activity implement View.OnClickListener and implement your click handling logic in the onClick method (more detail here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html), and in the onCreate, do this:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.concert);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I moved the code for onClick to the activity that is called initially. I have 2 activities, so I had to determine the correct one. Now the buttons have focus and onClick works.